# Does $P(f(X,Z)\leq x,Y\leq y|Z) = P(f(X,Z)\leq x|Z)P(Y\leq y|Z)$ for $X,Y$ indpendent

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ be two independent random variables and $Z$ is not independent from $X$ and $Y$. Can we say that $$P(f(X,Z)\leq x,Y\leq y|Z) = P(f(X,Z)\leq x|Z)P(Y\leq y|Z)$$
for some function $f$.

Comment: Please do not modify the question after some answers are posted, especially if this makes said answers appear offtopic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the identity was true, then using it for the function $f:(x,z)\mapsto x$, one would get that the independence of $(X,Y)$ implies the conditional independence of $(X,Y)$ conditionally on $Z$. But this is not so, as the usual examples of $(X,Y,Z)$ pairwise independent but not independent show. Thus, let $(X,Y)$ be i.i.d. uniform on $\{-1,1\}$ and $Z=XY$. Then, $(X,Z)$ is independent and $(Y,Z)$ is independent hence $$P(X\leqslant0\mid Z)=P(Y\leqslant0\mid Z)=\frac12,
$$
but
$$
P(X\leqslant0,Y\leqslant0\mid Z)=\frac12\mathbf 1_{Z=1}.$$

Comment: This is very nice observations! I forgot to mention that in my case the function is not actually such trivial. Do you have any idea what would happen in that case? For example, $f(x,z) = x+\$.

Comment: If $f$ is "not so trivial", this probably worsens the situation, no? The reason why I chose this function $f$ is to show that *even in such a simple case* the result fails.